# $scope.variable_name is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in order to improve my skills in angularjs, I have been working on websites using the particular framework. Now I am getting this error.

code for main-controller.js:

```
(function(){
angular.module('TimeWaste')
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    if(localStorage['User-Data'] !== undefined)
    {
        $scope.user = JSON.parse(localStorage['User-Data']);
        console.log($scope.user)
    }

    $scope.sendWaste = function(event) {
        if(event.which === 13)
        {
            var request = {
                user: $scope.user.username || $scope.user.email,
                userId: $scope.user_id,
                userImage: $scope.user.image,
                content: $scope.newWaste
            }

            $http.post('api/waste/post, request').success(function(response){
                console.log('fires')
            }).error(function(error){
                console.error(error);
            })
        }
    };
}]);
}());
```

I get this error through the console:

```
Error: $scope.user is undefined
$scope.sendWaste@http://localhost:3000/app/main/main-controller.js:15:6
anonymous/fn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js line 216 > 
Function:2:319
Jc[b]       .compile/</</e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:257:177
    rf/this.$get</r.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:133:442
rf/this.$get</r.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angu larjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:134:170
Jc[b]          .compile/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.    min.js:257:227 
m.event.dispatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:8497
m.event.add/r.handle@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:5235

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js
Line 107
```

From what I gather,`$user.scope` would `undefined` if `localStorage['User-Data']` is not defined.

But I already have the `localStorage['User-Data']` variable defined as

`"{"email":"pavan.vasan@gmail.com","_id":"56c19d3a2c0b68545bd97793","username":"PLSV927","image":"/uploads/56c19d3a2c0b68545bd97793Fri Feb 19 2016 19:42:37 GMT-0800 (PST)morningbikeride.jpg"}"`

can someone tell me what has gone wrong? is it because of `JSON.parse()` not working or is some simple mistake that I have overlooked? Please help me out

edit: My bad guys. I had made a mistake, instead of `$scope.user._id` in the code snippet, i had put it as `$scope.user_id`.....My apologies

Answer (score 1):

Convert this

```
$http.post('api/waste/post, request')
```

to this

```
$http.post('api/waste/post', request)
```

And declare `$scope.user` as an object at the beginning of controller

```
$scope.user={};
```

Answer (score 0):

angular.module('TimeWaste') should be angular.module('TimeWaste',[]) if this is your first instance of module.

https://plnkr.co/edit/LKkAUN0U2DqPIhxY5ms9?p=preview

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('TimeWaste', [])
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval',
      function($scope, $http, $interval) {
        $scope.user;
        if (localStorage['User-Data'] !== undefined) {
          $scope.user = JSON.parse(localStorage['User-Data']);
          console.log($scope.user)
        }

        $scope.sendWaste = function(event) {
          if (event.which === 13) {
            var request = {
              user: $scope.user.username || $scope.user.email,
              userId: $scope.user_id,
              userImage: $scope.user.image,
              content: $scope.newWaste
            }

            $http.post('api/waste/post', request).success(function(response) {
              console.log('fires')
            }).error(function(error) {
              console.error(error);
            })
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
}());
```